# How to create a running total in a core data based array

Tags: cocoa, core-data, binding

I am still learning about core data but understand the basics.

I am developing an expense tracking app using core data and bindings.  So far I can add, edit, sort and remove expense entities and also show the grand total for all expenses in a seperate text field and this works fine.

I would like to also display a running total column thats shows the running total for each of the expense amounts, that also still works if the expenses are sorted in any specific order.   I have searched all the answers on this site and others including the Apple docs on core data and KVC and bindings to try and find some example code but no luck.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the running total for each of the expense amounts'? Is that the total of each expense category? Maybe you can show the relevant relationships to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code I can't give you a working example, but it will involve asking your arrayController for arraignedObjects, getting a sub array of that based on the indexes and iterating through them to find the total...
Probably can online that process just to do it once for all objects since it is cumulative.

You will probably store those in an array of nsnumbers and use another array controller for binding.